# Get tweets sent in a specified time span

Tags: twitter, twitter-anywhere

I'm looking for a way to gather all the tweets sent by a user within a certain time span. I need it to implement pagination based on the date a tweet was sent. Apparently there is no way to gather something like "until" and "since". I'm working with the JavaScript Anywhere API.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method you may use: `GET statuses/user_timeline`
More info: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

There aren't any specific date range operators you can apply to this timeline, but because you can fetch up around 150-200 statuses per request. Then you could query against your now local dataset for the date ranges you're looking for.